# Katana+OWIN Multithreaded Performance?

Tags: iis, owin

Where can I find info on how many requests per second a Katana-on-OWIN implementation (Azure-hosted) can support?

There are performance benchmarks all over the place for IIS but I can't seem to find comparable data anywhere.

I am concerned that if I do something like this in a vacuum

```
public async Task Invoke(IDictionary<string, object> environment)
    {
        var response = environment["owin.ResponseBody"] as Stream;
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(response))
        {
            if (_options.IncludeTimestamp)
            {
                await writer.WriteAsync(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
            }
            await writer.WriteAsync("Hello, " + _options.Name + "!");
        }
    }
```

(taken from http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/11/11/writing-owin-middleware.aspx) and compare it to a simple .aspx.cs page that writes "Hello world" I will not get an apples-to-apples performance metric.

The way IIS handles threading and pooling is well-documented. But I am not sure about how Katana-on-OWIN (self hosted or under Azure) handles simultaneous requests and works "under load".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OWIN is merely an abstraction for running web applications on different web servers. Katana is one implementation. The most important performance numbers for requests/second are those for web servers, not OWIN or Katana.

OWIN performance comparisons would only make sense if you wanted to know how much overhead a framework added to your web app and could be tested using the [Microsoft.Owin.Testing](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Testing) `TestServer` in isolation of network latency. Here, you could compare differences in [Katana](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin), [Dyfrig](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Dyfrig), [NancyFx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nancy.Owin/), [Web API](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin), and others.